# Pytorch-lightining - cannot import name '_TRANSFORMERS_GREATER_EQUAL_4_4'

Tags: python, pytorch, python-import, importerror

When I try to make following imports:

```
import torch
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

from torchvision import datasets, transforms

from pytorch_lightning.core.lightning import LightningModule
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer
from torchmetrics.functional.classification.accuracy import accuracy
```

I get an import errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[77], line 8
      4 from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
      6 from torchvision import datasets, transforms
----> 8 from pytorch_lightning.core.lightning import LightningModule
      9 from pytorch_lightning import Trainer
     10 from torchmetrics.functional.classification.accuracy import accuracy

File d:\anaconda3\envs\dl\Lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\__init__.py:26
     23     _logger.propagate = False
     25 from lightning_fabric.utilities.seed import seed_everything  # noqa: E402
---> 26 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback  # noqa: E402
     27 from pytorch_lightning.core import LightningDataModule, LightningModule  # noqa: E402
     28 from pytorch_lightning.trainer import Trainer  # noqa: E402

File d:\anaconda3\envs\dl\Lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\__init__.py:14
      1 # Copyright The Lightning AI team.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
---> 14 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.batch_size_finder import BatchSizeFinder
     15 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.callback import Callback
...
---> 28 from torchmetrics.utilities.imports import _TRANSFORMERS_GREATER_EQUAL_4_4
     30 if _TRANSFORMERS_GREATER_EQUAL_4_4:
     31     from torchmetrics.functional.text.bert import bert_score

ImportError: cannot import name '_TRANSFORMERS_GREATER_EQUAL_4_4' from 'torchmetrics.utilities.imports' (d:\anaconda3\envs\dl\Lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\imports.py)
```

How to fix that? I have already tried to reinstall torch and  pytorch lightining. I also tried to install older version of pytorch-lightining and nothing has helped.

EDIT:
When downgrading torchmetrics to 0.7.0 import error messages has changed to:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'pit' from 'torchmetrics.functional.audio.pit' (d:\anaconda3\envs\dl\Lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\functional\audio\pit.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating new conda enviroment and reinstalling all libraries has helped. Also I have noticed that I used the old version of pytorch imports and it was necessary to change
`from pytorch_lightning.core.lightning import LightningModule`
to `import lightning.pytorch as pl` and then use `pl.LightningModule` according to documentation: https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/starter/introduction.html